# What does the linux kernel/initrd loading time depend on?

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, initrd

I recently updated my Linux kernel from 3.1.10 to 3.5.0. Upon booting with GRUB, I noticed that this kernel (or the initial ramdisk?) takes a much longer time to load (~5-6 s vs. ~1 s with the old kernel) before the rest of the booting process commences. The new kernel image is only about 100 kB larger than the old one and the initrd is pretty much the same size. The method of compression seems to be the same in both cases.
So I'm curious: what could be the cause for this significant change in delay? Can this time be reduced?

(By the way: I'm using openSUSE 12.1)

Comment: Where in the boot process is the delay? What the last line you see before the delay and the first line you see after it?

Comment: It must be the initrd. Right after selecting the menu entry in GRUB, I get a few lines, the last of which is mentioning the initrd for that specific kernel version. Then, a line flashes very shortly – it's very hard to read and I wouldn't know in which log file to find it – but it's something like initrd @ <somememoryaddress>. So I rather think the initial ramdisk is causing the delay. The next line after that, btw. is already hidden behind a bootsplash, but it is: doing fastboot.